# Java webservice (soap) client - use certificates

Tags: java, web-services, soap, certificate

I am trying to connect to a webservice over ssl with a client certificate. Is there an elegant way of doing this apart from shoving things like "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" into System.properties.

Any pointers to code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just install the cert into the system keystore. (Location varies across platforms, and you will need admin rights).

Answer (score 0):

you might get some samples from the website for this book : http://www.manning.com/kanneganti/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find) is fully relevant, but still. This entry describes the way of generating the certificate and installing it on a local system without using the keytool. Probably you could reuse some parts of the (very simple) source code.

Answer (score 0):

See example code in my article. It shows how to dynamically provide the custom keystore to the HTTPS server as for the WS client. http://jakubneubauer.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/java-webservice-over-ssl/