# How can we call a web service in java application?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I want to call a web service in my java application. How do I achieve this? I'm new to web services.

Comment: Which WS library are you planning to use? Apache CXF, Axis, JaxWS...

Comment: @romaintaz I think you gave him the anwser he needed :-)

Comment: A Google search for your exact title but with "servide" corrected to "service" found lots of useful tutorials etc. Which of these did you try, and what problems did you have with them?

Comment: Look at my brief answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666574/standalone-java-webservice-client/3666840#3666840). It's basically an overview of generating a java proxy from a web service definition in java.

Answer (score 1):

Go through [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html).

The basic steps are:

- download (if not already present) a JAX-WS implementation
- generate a java client by importing the wsdl with some tool (see below)
- invoke methods on the generated client code

[This article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) shows how to do it step by step using NetBean's wizards

Comment: The tutorial is from 2005.  Would a newer version reflect the annotation approach in Java 6?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Google and search for Webservice and Java.

Here is a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Apache foundation web site and search for the "AXIS SOAP client"!

This is well documented and the client side consists of a single JAR file.

Also I would thourogly recommend SOAPUI for generating and reading test messages.

Comment: AXIS mature, bug free, well documented.